# Fetch a user's email from UID in firebase auth react native

Tags: react-native, firebase-authentication, react-native-firebase

How can I find a specific user's email by having their UID? I'm using the `react-native-firebase` library, but I can't find anything in the [documentation](https://rnfirebase.io/reference/auth) to find a user by their UID, and obtain their email after.

Am I missing out something?

Comment: Are you trying to get the logged-in user's email or arbitrary other users' emails?

Comment: @jnpdx No, I'm not trying to get the logged-in user's email. I just have the UID of an arbitrary user and I want to get their email.

Comment: I think you're either going to have to write a cloud function to get it or store the email in the database. I don't think you can access those auth properties for separate users, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @jnpdx I think you're probably right, as there's nothing in the documentation to access the auth properties.
In this case, I guess the easiest solution would be storing the emails in the database, as you said.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I don't think so, the question is totally different and also, my question is mostly about `react-native-firebase`, not firebase itself.

Comment: The Firebase SDKs are quite similar across platforms. Since Firebase doesn't have an option for getting properties for another user that the one that is logged in, neither does the `react-native-firebase` that is implemented on top of Firebase.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there isn't any way to obtain a specific user's properties in Firebase.

In my case, the easiest solution was to use a real-time database to save the emails of the users under their UID in the database after signing them up.